# C strings initialization. Possible trouble

Tags: c, string, initialization, 32bit-64bit

Good day everyone. I have the following c-string initialization:
`*(str) = 0;` where str is declared as `char str[255];`. The questions are:

1) is it the best way to initialize a string this way?

2) should I expect trouble with this code on 64-bit platform?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What has the "64-bit platform" to do with anything?!

Comment: You can write `s[0] = 0;` or `s[0] = '\0';` if you prefer; it looks cleaner to me. But it's the same thing. Or instead write `char str[255] = { 0 };`, but that zeroes *every* element.

Comment: This is something of a noob question (i.e. something that could be answered trivially with a web search), which is, I imagine, why you're getting downvoted.  However, the CPU will just write out the single octet at the beginning of the string regardless of the CPU architecture.  This behaviour is defined in the specification of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction `*(str) = 0` is completely equivalent to `str[0] = 0;`.

The initiatlization simply place the integer `0` (which is equivalent to `'\0'`) in the first position, making the string empty.

1) There's no "best way", the key is being consistent so if you choose the "`*(str) = 0;`" path, always do the same everywhere.

2) No trouble could ever come from that statement. Whatever the architecture, the compiler will take care of everything.

Answer (score 0):

What this does is change the uninitialized `char` array `str`, of which each element has some undefined value, to have its first element set to the null terminator character.

As far as most string related functions go, they will traverse this string from left to right, and immediately see the null terminator.

There are surely functions that don't care about null terminators, and are given a maximum size. In these cases, you are reading undefined values, which is Bad™.

Use this instead:

```
char str[255] = { 0 }; // zero every element
```

or initialize the string to something useful on first use.